# javascript - add spaces after commas and full stops, but not if it is a decimal separator

Tags: javascript, regex, addition, space

I have a form with a text field in it which is to fill up with users of a website. Users usually do not put spaces after commas and full stops. How can be formated with javascript this text area, in order to add spaces after theese comma and full stop characters, but to leave those characters, that represents decimal separators for numbers. I have tried with `replace(/\,/g,', ')` but this put space after decimal separator of a number too.

Thank you

Comment: there is no way to tell the difference on `1,200,40` between 1.2k, 40 and 1, 200, 40. It is impossible.

Comment: but maybe with a look behind you can see if the char on the left of the comma is number, and will work in most cases unless someone writes something like "my lucky number is 7,4 out of 5 cats purr"

Comment: For me it is ok, if will work in the 95 % of the cases, but I am newbie in javacript enviroment, I dont know what to do.

Comment: @ajax333221: lookbehinds aren't supported by the javascript regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is non-RegExp solution using split:

```js
function fixString(inp){
    var i, len, arr, outp, Rside, Lside, RsideIsNum, LsideIsNum;

    arr = inp.split(",");
    outp = "";

    for(i=1, len=arr.length; i<len; i++){
        Lside = arr[i-1];
        Rside = arr[i];

        LsideIsNum = /\d/.test(Lside.charAt(Lside.length-1));
        RsideIsNum = /\d/.test(Rside.charAt(0));

        outp += "," + ((LsideIsNum && RsideIsNum)?"":" ") + Rside;
    }

    return (arr[0] + outp).replace(/\s\s+/g," ");
}
```

then to use it simply call `fixString(my_string)` like this:

```
var str_old = "a,1b,c,d2,e,3f4,g, this is a test, 1,000 yay!,2,000,ok?";
var str_new = fixString(str_old);

//str_old: a,1b,c,d2,e,3f4,g, this is a test, 1,000 yay!,2,000,ok?
//str_new: a, 1b, c, d2, e, 3f4, g, this is a test, 1,000 yay!, 2,000, ok?
```

However, as I said in the comments, you will get unexpected results when someone says `"my lucky number is 7,4 out of 5 cats purr"`.

Comment: This removes breaks/new lines too. It is possible to remove only duplicates spaces? Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution. I use replace(/ {2,}/g, " "); insted of your, now everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups and a negative digit identifier.

```
var test = "i believe.1.5.today";
test = test.replace(/([^\d])\.([^\d])/g,'$1. $2').replace(/([\d])\.([^\d])/g,'$1. $2').replace(/([^\d])\.([\d])/g,'$1. $2')
// test == "i believe. 1.5. today"
```

However, if you have 2 sentences separated by 2 numbers, for example, "... blah 1.2 is the number ..." then this won't insert a space.

You can extend the regex for commas or just use the same template.

Comment: I've tried but for Octavia 1.6 FSi 116 ps.Frissen beiratva. gave me Octavia 1. 6 FSi 116 ps. Frissen beiratva. so put space after decimal

Comment: Sorry about that.  I couldn't think of a way to do this with a single regex, but chaining 3 of them works fine.

Comment: Thank you, it is working well. What disadvantages has if there are 3 regex chained? How can apply this for more then 1 symbol, I mean for full stops and exclamation mark etc in one replace. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: you have some double spaces issue http://jsfiddle.net/2VcKK/3/

Comment: True, but those only look evident (at a quick glance) when there is weird input like `. .. .`.  This could probably be accounted for in a more advanced regex or at least a simple extensions that ignores non-special characters (like dot and space) surrounding the target separator character.

Comment: 3 chained regexes are slower than a unified single regex as the string needs to be traversed 3 times instead of 1.  To account for multiple character types as a separator you can use a 3 capturing group of character classes.  For example, replace `\.` with (and I'm guessing at the escaping here) `([\.\!\,])` and change your replacement to `$1$2 $3`.

Comment: @disrvptor or just adding `.replace(/\s\s+/g," ")` at the end :)

Comment: interesting, your answer turns `"a.b.c2.d"` into `"a. b.c2. d"` http://jsfiddle.net/2VcKK/5/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add more context to the regex -- maybe something like the comma has to be touching a letter?, `replace(/[a-zA-Z]?,.?/gi, ', ')`

Comment: This eliminates the letters before and after comma